# Pagination adds an extra blank page at the end

Tags: pagination, jasper-reports

Given the footer of my report :

```
<pageFooter>
        <band height="51" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType = "Float" x="485" y="1" width="55" height="50" uuid="7786fb05-689a-4b6a-915a-a7bcf3abad95"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="10" />
                    <paragraph lineSpacingSize="0"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" - "]]> + $V{PAGE_NUMBER} + <![CDATA[" - "]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
</pageFooter>
```

My report adds an extra blank page without page number at the end of the report unlike the previous report pages each of which has a page number. When I have tried to remove the pagination and use a `staticText` component as my footer, the extra blank page is gone.

[image]

How could one solve this problem please?

Comment: Could you post an image? Your question is unclear

Comment: @Alex : Here's a screenshot of the last two pages of my 9 pages+ extra blank page report : http://imgur.com/a/TQvC8

Comment: Is it pdf output?

Comment: It is an MS Word .docx

Comment: Looks like the engine calculated that there is no enough empty space to render text block at this page

Comment: So what do you suggest as a solution ? Sould I modify something in my .jrxml or java source code?

Comment: 1) Try to modify design - decrease height of elements, remove empty spaces between elements, decrease font size, fix positions; 2) Try to play with `splitType`, `isStretchWithOverflow`,  `positionType` properties;  3) Try to use another font

Comment: After trying several tricks, I ended up with the following deductions :
- Using the same source code on IReport does not add any extra blank page.
- The extra page is appended at the exportation time and not at the compilation/filling time. 
- The JRDocxExporter version I am using is 4.6.0 which is older than IReport's version 5.6.0

Comment: BTW, There are two exporters for MS Word

Comment: Could you please provide me with both classes' names and what difference between the two that might be relevant to my problem ?

Comment: I don't know what version you are using, but here is the list: `JRXlsExporter, JRXlsxExporter, JExcelApiExporter`